# SVG path not supported in Safari but working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I designed a white wave image in SVG format, and it is displaying properly in Google Chrome but not in Safari:

```html
<svg class="header_angle header_angle_03" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 15">
        <path fill="#ccc" d="M0 30 V12 Q30 17 55 12 T100 11 V30z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: works for me, what Safari version?

Comment: @Rikin version - 12.0.1

Comment: Run this Stackoverflow url in safari to see if it works for you. I changed color to grey so that you can see instead of white which blends with background.

Comment: @Rikin svg path displaying thorugh this url in safari but when i open my website svg path not displaying .. you can check my site http://www.mteapro.com/

Comment: works in there too, its just your positioning is off in Safari thus not displayed correctly. Try some background color to see it.